# dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Realm.framework/Realm error with Realm Objective C framework

Tags: objective-c, realm, xcode8

I have installed the Realm Objective C Framework (2.0.3) by simply dragging it into my project created in Xcode 8. When I first tried it on simulator I got the typical dyld error.

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Realm.framework/Realm
Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/89F5987A-F3F0-45F2-9014-6BA662135E00/RelamDemo.app/RelamDemo
Reason: image not found
```

So I tried to fix it using the following suggestion:
https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1681#issuecomment-120749962

And it worked on iOS 10 Simulators.

But when I tried to run the same project on a device (iOS 10/9.3.2) I got the same dyld error again.

I have checked that I have copied the Realm.framework in my project. Now how can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to ensure that `Realm.framework` is also copied to the 'Embedded Binaries' section of your app as well.

You can find that section in the 'General' tab of your project's settings.

[image: Embedded Binaries]

(Screenshot courtesy of [this iOSDevCenter post](https://iosdevcenters.blogspot.com/2015/12/realm-error-dyld-library-not-loaded.html))